# Cannot restart typedef'd 2D array whose address is saved in struct

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct, typedef

I have this `typedef` and `struct`:

```
typedef double mat[MAT_SIZE][MAT_SIZE];

typedef struct matList {
    char *name;
    mat *matrix;
} matList;
```

and I create an array of pointers to my structure:

```
    mat MAT_A, MAT_B, MAT_C, MAT_D, MAT_E, MAT_F;
    matList *mats[MAT_COUNT];
    int i;
    
    for (i = 0; i < MAT_COUNT; i++) {
        mats[i] = NULL;
    }
    mats[0] = create_mat("MAT_A", &MAT_A);
    mats[1] = create_mat("MAT_B", &MAT_B);
    mats[2] = create_mat("MAT_C", &MAT_C);
    mats[3] = create_mat("MAT_D", &MAT_D);
    mats[4] = create_mat("MAT_E", &MAT_E);
    mats[5] = create_mat("MAT_F", &MAT_F);
```

my `create_mat` function look like this:

```
matList *create_mat(char *name, mat *curMat) {
    matList *tempMat = (matList *)malloc(sizeof(matList));

    if (tempMat != NULL) {
        tempMat->name = name;
        tempMat->matrix = curMat;
        return tempMat;
    }
    free(tempMat);
    tempMat = NULL;
    return NULL;
}
```

and I am tying to get to the two dimensional array and put 0 in all the cells but it doesn't work:

- sometimes I have a core dump (but it succeeds putting the 0)
- sometimes I don't get a core dump but I don't have zero in all the cells

```
void restart_mat(matList *mats[]) {
    int i, j, k;

    if (mats == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    for (k = 0; k < MAT_COUNT; k++) {
        if (mats[k] != NULL) {
            for (i = 0; i < MAT_SIZE; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < MAT_SIZE; j++) {
                     mats[k]->matrix[0][i][j] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Related: a recent [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72233696/stack-smashing-detected-when-trying-to-get-to-typedef-two-dinatial-array-that-th). If that solved a particular problem please accept the best answer.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as text, the shortest *complete* code that shows what you have tried. May I suggest you take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) As advised yesterday, but not followed up.

Comment: What is the purpose of `matList`? It does not look to have anything to do with a typical linked list.

Answer (score 1):

The 2D arrays `MAT_A, MAT_B, MAT_C, MAT_D, MAT_E, MAT_F` are defined as local objects with automatic storage in the function that calls `create_mat`. A pointer to these arrays is set in the allocated `matList` structure. These arrays must no longer be referenced after the function returns.

Unless there is a compelling reason to allocate the 2D arrays and the `matList` structures separately, you should define the matrix as a struct member instead of a pointer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAT_SIZE   4
#define MAT_COUNT  6

typedef double mat[MAT_SIZE][MAT_SIZE];

typedef struct matList {
    const char *name;
    mat matrix;
} matList;

void init_mat(mat m) {
    for (int i = 0; i < MAT_SIZE; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < MAT_SIZE; j++) {
            m[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

matList *create_mat(const char *name) {
    matList *tempMat = malloc(sizeof(*tempMat));
    if (tempMat != NULL) {
        tempMat->name = name;
        init_mat(tempMat->matrix);
    }
    return tempMat;
}

void free_matList(matList **mats) {
    if (mats) {
        for (int i = 0; i < MAT_COUNT; i++) {
            free(mats[i]);
            mats[i] = NULL;
        }
    }
}

// return non zero if successful
int allocate_matList(matList **mats) {
    if (mats) {
        for (int i = 0; i < MAT_COUNT; i++) {
            mats[i] = NULL;
        }
        mats[0] = create_mat("MAT_A");
        mats[1] = create_mat("MAT_B");
        mats[2] = create_mat("MAT_C");
        mats[3] = create_mat("MAT_D");
        mats[4] = create_mat("MAT_E");
        mats[5] = create_mat("MAT_F");
        if (mats[0] && mats[1] && mats[2] && mats[3] && mats[4] && mats[5])
            return 1;
        free_matList(mats);
    }
    return 0;
}

void restart_matList(matList **mats) {
    if (mats != NULL) {
        for (int k = 0; k < MAT_COUNT; k++) {
            if (mats[k] != NULL)
                init_mat(mats[k]->matrix);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    matList *mats[MAT_COUNT];
    allocate_matList(mats);
    restart_matList(mats);
    free_matList(mats);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hey. trying to understand your answer. copy the exact code. plus int main(void){}. while compile it,there were so many errors. can your further explain it....

Comment: @jian: I fixed the compilation, missing definitions for `MAT_COUNT` and `MAT_SIZE` and fixed the prototypes for `allocate_matList()` and `restart_matList()`. Also added `free_matList()` to release memory.